# Why does this JavaScript execute only in Opera?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a web site that cleanly separates the HTML presentation from the JavaScript behavior.

To gain experience in this, I have created a simple "Hello, world!" site with one page and one behavior. The page contains a "Hello, world!" message, and the JavaScript displays a similar message to the user through an alert box.

To implement this, I have created two files on my local machine called index.html and sayhello.js.

The HTML file index.html contains this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Helo, world!</h1>
    <p>That's all for now.</p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="sayhello.js"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript file sayhello.js contains this:

```
alert('Hello, world!');
```

My operating system is Windows 7.

I open index.html in Opera 11 and see a "Hello, world!" dialog pop up as soon as the page opens.

In Firefox 4, Chrome 11, and IE 9, I don't see the pop up. It's as if the JavaScript is being ignored.

Why doesn't the alert box show up in all browsers? What can I do to make it show in all?

Comment: That should work in all browsers i see no reason why it should not

Comment: @Neal - check the script element, no closing tag

Comment: @Neal Look more closely!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `<script>` tag is not self-closing. You need to write

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sayhello.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost all browsers don't like self closing tags for the `script` tag.

So simply replace it with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sayhello.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer is equivalent to the accepted answer, but I can only accept one, and Graham Clark answered first.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the other succinct answers, I did a bit of reading and found that the fundamental problem is that I'm confusing HTML and XML constructs.

According to this [post from the WebKit team](http://www.webkit.org/blog/68/understanding-html-xml-and-xhtml/), self-closing tags in HTML might work because of how leniantly HTML parsers handle errors, and not because they understand the self-closing syntax:

> When XML and XHTML were first
>   standardized, no browser supported
>   them natively. To enable at least
>   partial use of XHTML, the W3C came up
>   with something called “HTML-compatible
>   XHTML”. This is a set of guidelines
>   for making valid XHTML documents that
>   can still more or less be processed as
>   HTML. The basic idea is to use
>   self-closing syntax for tags where
>   HTML doesn’t want a close tag, like
>   img, br or link, with an extra space
>   before the slash. So our ever-popular
>   image example would look like this:
>   `<img src="funfun.jpg" />`. The details
>   are described in the Appendix C of the
>   XHTML 1.0 standard.
>
> It’s important to note that this is
>   kind of a hack, and depends on the de
>   facto error handling behavior of HTML
>   parsers. They don’t really understand
>   the XML self-closing syntax, but
>   writing things this way makes them
>   treat / as an attribute, and then
>   discard it because it’s not a legal
>   attribute name. And if you tried to do
>   something like , they wouldn’t
>   understand that the div is supposed to
>   be empty.

Seems like the safest thing for me to do is just to close all my tags the long way.

Comment: You need to close all your `<script>` tags, but don't add closing tags to ones that don't need them. You're using HTML 5 in your example, so you don't need the self-closing tags at all. You can just use `<br>`, `<hr>`, `<img>`, etc on their own and the browser will be fine.

Comment: Some browsers will treat `<br></br>` as `<br><br>`. So follow the HTML compatibility guidelines and use self-closing syntax for elements defined as being EMPTY in HTML 4. Better yet - don't use XHTML.